# Basic SQL table structure

Tags: sql, database

Say I have a few tables such as:

1. Products
2. Employees
3. Facilities
4. *Schedule_Events

In the Schedule_Events table, I'd have columns for start_time, end_time, notes etc...

My question is, if I need to schedule employees, products or facilities, what is the proper structure to follow.

Should the product/employee/facility tables link directly to Schedule_Events...

such as:
Schedule_Events (Table)

- Schedule_Event_ID
- Employee_ID
- Product_ID
- Facility_ID

...and basically link the foreign keys when applicable, or do I need a bunch of sub tables...

- Schedule_Events_Employees
- Schedule_Events_Facilities
- Schedule_Events_Products

**OR**

a table called Schedule_Event_Items that contains all of the above...

Or some other table design I'm not considering?

I'm pretty new at this, any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They should link directly with foreign keys to each of the three tables.  It's much easier to follow than creating three different tables that make up the same thing.

Comment: you should probably have a few more tables.. `Events`   `EventSchedules`  `ProductEventSchedules`  `EmployeeEventSchedules`  `FacilityEventSchedules`

Answer (score 0):

The first suggestion will not work if some of the records are one to many. If more that one employee can be associated with an event, then the design is flawed and cannot be used.

The standard way to solve that problem is with the linking tables (Schedule_Events_Employees,Schedule_Events_Facilities,Schedule_Events_Products) so that you can have many to many relationships which is what the data likely calls for. You could put them all in one table and add a column for teh type but then you lose the power of the FKs and you still end up joining to that table 3 times to get all the data. So there is no advantage to the third possibility.